# Conversion from excel file which includes russian letters to pdf using php excel

Tags: php, excel, pdf, phpexcel

I have a file in excel and I am converting it to pdf using phpexcel. It is displaying russian letters as ????

Here is the code that is responsible for conversion:

```
 public function exportToExcel($phpExcelObject)
{
    header("Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel", 'charset=UTF-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=matrix.xls");
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($phpExcelObject);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Could you please  help me?

Comment: Which bit of this code does anything with PDF? This is creating an xls file

Answer (score 0):

First, check the folder which includes fonts supported by domPDF. Then, If there are any font which ends with .ttf, apply this font-family to the corresponding cells of PhpExcel  Object. Then it works.

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setName('dejavu sans');
```